# Sending data to server every second with http-request

Tags: sensors

I'm sending few bytes of sensor data to server with http.POST every minute and it's working. Next I want to send 20 bytes every second with http.POST. I was told server would take that as an attack and block it.

How should I send data in this case? Potentially there would be more sensors and there would be multiple http-requests every second.

Comment: how do you know that the server would block the POST messages?

Comment: It would probably make more sense to use Websockets for this, especially if you use HTTPS (as you should).

Comment: Or MQTT, but without knowing what the server/service is we really don't have enough information work with here

Comment: @hardillb or MQTT over Websockets :-)

Comment: Who told you that? Whoever told you that must be the administrator of that server, and **only** they know what your application mustn't do. Anyway, an HTTP request every second hardly seems like something a web server would block. Quite the contrary, that's a relatively common usage pattern. So, maybe ask whoever told you that what they base that on.

Comment: Websockets sound like made for this. I'll read more about that and make some tests. Thanks.

Comment: While websockets will also work, consider IoT using MQTT. AWS and Microsoft have the entire chain of data extraction, processing, storage, analytics, actions, etc all easily available. (Can be adapted to websockets too, but IoT looks like a better fit.)